# Gulp is compiling every Js-file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

i have a problem with my gulp.
Its works fine and its really fast but Gulp is compiling all js files in my project...

my gulp-watch:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(sassFilesWatch, ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(jsFilesWatch, ['uglify'])
});
```

My array:

```
var jsFilesWatch = [
    'clients/*/template/lib/jscripts/*.js',
    'clients/*/template/modules/**/*.js',
    'system/lib/jscripts/*.js',
    'system/mod/**/*.js',
    'clients/core/modules/**/*.js',
    '!/**/*.min.js'
];
```

Thats my function:

```
gulp.task('uglify', function(){
    pump([
        gulp.src(jsFilesWatch, {
            base: './'
        }),
        debug({
            title: 'Compiled',
            showFiles: false,
        }),
        uglify(),
        rename({ suffix: '.min' }),
        gulp.dest('./')
    ]);
});
```

And thats the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpEeC.png)

Just my saved file should be compiled
how can i do that?

thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It seems all your files with .js extensions are
being debugged, uglified and minified.
Which saved file are you trying to compile?

**/*.js uses the gulp command to watch all files with the .js extension in all folders.

You could use .pipe()

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('js', function() {
gulp.src('scripts/*.js')
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(concat('script.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('assets'))
});
```

Comment: Well, i want to compile my changed file. its unnecessary which file. 

I want to compile the file in the same directory as the .js not in a assets folder or something like this.

I already tried it with pipe. Same result..

Comment: Hard to say from the info you provide, but from your reply I understand that the file you changed does not output in the respective folder.

Comment: Uhm, for example:
i have a  "js" directory .. in this directory is a main.js and a test.js

When i compile the main.js i dont want to compile it in a "assets" folder. 

It should compile / uglify in the "js" folder to a main.min.js

i hope this is understandable for you

Comment: Yes, I could not extract that from your original question.  Try `gulp.dest('./js');`  You might also look into gulp-concat to merge the files together 
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look into this Plugin, That will solve your problem

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-changed

Try Changing your task to,

```
gulp.task('uglify', function(){
    pump([
        gulp.src(jsFilesWatch, {
            base: './'
        }),
        changed('dist'),
        ngAnnotate(),
        debug({
            title: 'Compiled',
            showFiles: false,
        }),
        uglify(),
        rename({ suffix: '.min' }),
        gulp.dest('./')
    ]);
});
```

Note: this might run all your `.js` files at first time after you run your task, but it will identify the changed file on subsequent runs